# Who came first among our supreme gods

Tags: gods

Actually i have seen in many references about the first god but always answer is not clear.....            I want to know that among the three supreme gods shiv vishnu brahma and also goddess durga who came first.......                             Some says its brahma who gave birth to all gods either directly or indirectly 
some says shiv because he is God of gods therefore he must have been came earlier 
some says vishnu as he is the protector of all and also for many problems gods visited him for solution 
and some says goddess durga as she is considered as the mother of all creatures 
I want to know so can you please help me?

Comment: Yes. The answer is always unclear. Vishnu came first. But Shiva came first. But Devi came first. It is not known. Also. There is no difference in Shakti, Shiva, Vishnu, Ganesha et cetera..... so one came first and all came first, as all are one and one is all.